# Remove query from php echo url call

Tags: php, url, request, echo

I'm trying to create a canonical tag only for the homepage, but because I'm using a generic call he shows any URL, even if we are in the homepage but with different URL.

Ex.

In this URL: http://www.example.com/?something=here, I want to put a canonical tag URL on the homepage without the query.

But if I'm in another URL (for example /contact.php), I want it to show the same URL for canonical with the /contact.php.

I'm using this code that retrieves the URL where I am in the website:

```
<link rel="canonical" href=<?php $url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; echo $url; ?>" />
```

Something is missing in the code to remove only specific queries or words. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no one comand / global that can get you the segment/uri part without the parameters. You could split the code like this:

```
<?php
$uri = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
$url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$uri[0];
?>
<link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo $url; ?>" />
```

Of course this assumes that you'll be using only plain http, because all https requests will have a http canonical link tag instead of https.

The code gets the full uri and convert the string in an array using the "?" separator (this is the params separator for a proper uri), so you'll end up with the segment based / scriptname part of the uri in the first member of the array.
If you need to acces the params, all you have to do is verify the content of `$_GET` - which is an array ( according to your example it will be `$_GET = array('something' => 'here')`